# Get location from IOS device

Tags: positioning, service-worker, here-api

In the https://app.tracking.here.com  dashboard, I can not add an IOS device yet. I see the message 'coming soon'. Is it possible to get (e.g. every 10 minutes) the location of an IOS device, by using a web app. Even when the phone is stand by.
Or is there maybe another way the get the location of IOS devices?

Use case: from a group of engineers we want to get there current location every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there maybe another way the get the location of IOS devices?

You can use HERE IOS SDK.

Take a look at [NMAPositioningManager](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAPositioningManager.html) and its [NMADevicePositionSource](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMADevicePositionSource.html) dataSource.

Check positioning sample apps on [Github](https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples).